# UINavigationBar appears as ViewController is launched

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a Main UIViewController where the navigation bar is hidden.

However when I present a view modally, as my new ViewController is sliding up, the navigation bar appears briefly on Main before the new View Controller has occupied the entire screen.

```
[self presentViewController:settingsController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Has anyone had this happen and know what could be causing it? I want the navigation bar to remain hidden.

Thanks

Comment: You want to hide navigation bar in settingsController?

Comment: No, I didn't say that. Think of settingsController as a blank white controller for now. And the nav bar is hidden on mainController. When I launch settingsController using the above code, the navigation bar briefly appears on mainController before the blank settingsController takes over the screen. Am I making sense? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have done;

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Then you will get that (side) effect. Try commenting that first line. Let me know if it works.